# Efficiently test events with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I'm testing a rather large project, and everything is fine except for events (that is EventEmitter / event.js from node) where I have to change the environment to get different outcomes from the same event.

My current setup looks as follows:

```
beforeEach((done)=> {
        //<sets up some stuff> 


       //<sets up spies >

        <the_Event_Emitter>.emit('keyword1');


        setTimeout(() => {
            done();
        },1);

    });
```

and then in the specs are just the expects.

Which works perfectly but I'd have to write an entire describe-Block with a specific beforeAll-block for EVERY variant to the environment (the event in question has a switch-case over some variable)

making the beforeEach-block look like this:

```
<the_Event_Emitter>.emit('keyword1');
<change Environment>
<the_Event_Emitter>.emit('keyword1');
...
```

would "work" but is unacceptably unclean, with calls leaking into the wrong specs etc.

Is there a decent way of doing this?
The waitFor() from the old (pre 2.0) Jasmine would have solved ALL my problems with ease.

[I tried having no beforeEach ( the .emit etc. within the spec) but that doesnt work since events run asynchronously, so the code in question is run AFTER the expects have been tried (and failed becuase the code hasn't run yet)]

EDIT: 
I now "did" it by setting the environment in the previous test.
Which is fine as long as the tests run all and in order (which is not proper unit testing as fas as I know...)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your tests in a for-each block?  Set up an array of objects for the set of expected inputs and outputs and put the describe/expects inside the body of the loop?

Comment: @axlj  but I have different expects depending on  the environment, how would that look (I miight be missung your point)? (or be better than just writing the 15 describe blocks manually?)

Comment: My thought is that: The type of things you are checking are the same but the outputs you expect are different.  In such a case you could parameterize your tests by the method i mentioned above.  If this is not the case (ie. business logic is completely different) then my method won't work.